# How I can increase the url number in load more data in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am implment show more data button that's data came from API (backend)

and the api url have number when this number `(visable)` change the data change

```
.post(`/account/api/auth/user/${userName}/posts/more/${visible}/`)
```

I created function that increse number by 3 but it seems not to work and the api had same number without change

```
         $('#show_more_posts_button').on('click', ()=>{
                  visible += 3
                  console.log(visible)
                  this.showMore()
            })
```

This the function of load more button

```
         async showMore() {
       var visible = 3
          
        this.buttonText = 'Loading more images...';
            const userName = this.$route.params.username
 

           await axios
           .post(`/account/api/auth/user/${userName}/posts/more/${visible}/`).then(response => {
            
            this.more = response.data.data

              });
        this.buttonText = 'Show More';
    },
```

The button of show more data

```
 <button class="show_more_button" id="show_more_posts_button" ><p class="Show_more_profile">Show More  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" ></i></p></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ahmed it's hard to tell how all the pieces fit together from the amount of code you've shared, but within your `showMore` function you're instantiating a new variable called `visibile` and assigning it's value to `3` each time. So within this function it will always be `3`.
This part here

```
async showMore() {
  var visible = 3
  ...etc...
```

How about alternatively, from within the below on click listener, you instead pass in the newly updated `visible` variable as an argument to `showMore`. ie

```
$('#show_more_posts_button').on('click', ()=>{
  visible += 3
  console.log(visible)
  this.showMore(visible)
})
```

which would change your `showMore` function to look like

```
async showMore(visible) {
          
  this.buttonText = 'Loading more images...';
  const userName = this.$route.params.username
 
  await axios.post(`/account/api/auth/user/${userName}/posts/more/${visible}/`).then(response => {        
    this.more = response.data.data
  });
  this.buttonText = 'Show More';
  },
```

Comment: when I click on button it is change the number many times not just one time, Is I add function on click inside the `showMore()` function